# Scaling property of Big-O and it's prove

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

What exactly is a scaling property of Big-O and how can we prove it ?

Understanding so far: 
**proof: cf(n) < (c + E)f(n) holds for all n > 0 and E > 0.**

Constant factors are ignored.

Only the powers and functions of n should be exploited.

It is this ignoring of constant factors that gives us such a notation. In particular, f is O(f).

Comment: You should be able to prove that pretty easily with induction by picking simple values for n and E.

Comment: ahmm got that but I how can i explain that for any constant c > 0, cf(n) is O(f(n))? will the above proof by plugging a value of n and E be enough to prove?

Comment: `cf(n) ≤ cf(n)` for all `n`, and therefore, by [definition of Big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), cf(n) = O(f(n).

Comment: **Trying to prove: If f(n) and g(n) are both O(h(n)), then f(n)*g(n) is O(h
^2 . Any ideas on that?**If g1(n) <= c1f1(n)    for n > n1 and

 g2(n) <= c2f2(n)     for n > n2,

then g1(n).g2(n) <= c1.c2.f1(n).f2(n) for n > max(n1,n2)
.